# NextJs : Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Create By Fyz" Client: "Back"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, header, next.js13

So i make i dynamic header that has some props like this

```
//header.jsx
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="...">
        <Link href={props.link} className={style}>
          {props.tag}
        </Link>
        <div className="...">
          <Link href="/documentations" className={style}>
            Documentations
          </Link>
          <Link href="/others">
            Others
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also, i have some [ages that i want they consume a header component with different props with the default header.This in my RootLayout of my nextJs project

```
 <Header link='/' tag="Create By Fyz" />
```

this is my header component if user is in localhost/documentations

```
<Header link="/" tag="Back"/>
```

this is my header if user in localhost/documentations/something

```
<Header link="/documentations" tag="Back"/>
```

Actually, my UI is going good, i mean their header is showing but if I am in "localhost/" then i go to  "localhost/documentations" then "localhost/documentations/something" then i back to "localhost/documentations/" there is a error Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Create By Fyz" Client: "Back" and hydrating error

This my picture of my website

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDkmP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHXCu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjAeW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUiC0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWwXp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5rqy.png)

there is no error more, and i can navigate easily from home to documentations to something and back again